# WP8 Change pivot header color (selected / unselected)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I need to change a pivot header color but still have a different color for selected and unselected pivot item headers.

I can easily change the color of all the headers but i really need a way to differentiate selected and unselected pivot items.

I have tried many ways to do this for windows phone 7 but the pivot header architecture seem to have changed and the styles no longer work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I couldn't find a direct way of doing this by for example creating a new headertemplate, but you change this applicationwide by overriding the correct solidcolorbrushes in the theme dictionary. So in App.xaml:

```
<Application>
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
          <SolidColorBrush
            x:Key="PivotHeaderForegroundUnselectedBrush"
            Color="Purple"/>
        <SolidColorBrush
            x:Key="PivotHeaderForegroundSelectedBrush"
            Color="Orange"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
      </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

This is not a completely foolproof approach, it is explained in more detail at http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208807

Comment: this is even better then what i wanted as i do want it to be changed applicationwide. thanks